# How do you view a numpy broadcast object?

Tags: python, numpy

According to [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) :

```
>>> a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
>>> b = np.array([2.0, 2.0, 2.0])
>>> a * b
array([ 2.,  4.,  6.])
```

Cool, makes sense. The elements in the array which are aligned get multiplied.

I then noticed [there is another way to](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html#numpy.broadcast) use broadcast; by using the keyword np.broadcast(a,b)

The documentation states that you create a broadcast image by imputing np.broadcast(a,b). However, it does not state explicitly how to **view** this object once it is created.

It gives an example of how to do, but does not explain exactly what is going on in the example:

```
>>> out = np.empty(b.shape)
>>> out.flat = [u+v for (u,v) in b]
>>> out
array([[ 5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to use [np.broadcast_arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html) to see what `x` and `y` look like after being broadcasted to the same shape:

```
In [32]: x = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])    
In [33]: y = np.array([4, 5, 6])

In [37]: x, y = np.broadcast_arrays(x, y)

In [38]: x
Out[38]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])

In [39]: y
Out[39]: 
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [40]: x+y
Out[40]: 
array([[5, 6, 7],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the contents of a `numpy.broadcast` object by converting it to a list.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
>>> y = np.array([4, 5, 6])
>>> b = np.broadcast(x, y)
>>> b
<numpy.broadcast object at 0xad0310>
>>> list(b)
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `broadcast` using your 1st arrays is:

```
In [350]: a = np.array([1,2,3]); b=np.array([2,2,2])
In [351]: ab=list(np.broadcast(a,b))
# [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)]
In [353]: list([i*j for i,j in ab])
Out[353]: [2, 4, 6]
```

'broadcasting' gets more interesting when the arrays have different dimensions, as shown your 2nd example (column vector and a row vector).

The `broadcast` example isn't meant to used in production.  It illustrates what is going on when you do something like `a*b`.