# Understanding Python's "colon operator" when summing arrays of multiple dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've a probably simple question about how to understand the colon operator when performing mathematical operations on arrays of multiple dimensions.

Here are two examples where im quite confused about what actually happens:

```
dx[:,r:H,c:W] += dout[depth, r, c] * w[depth,:,:,:]
```

In this example, we are dealing with with an array `dx` of shape `(channels, height, width)`. For example an RGB image. `dout` is similar, but the number of channels, rows and columns is different to `dx`. `w` has the shape `(num, channels, height, width)` where `channels` is equal to `channels` in `dx`. `dout`'s `channels` is equal to `w`'s `num`.

```
dw[depth,:,:,:] += dout[depth,r,c] * x[:,r:r+HH,c+WW]
```

Here `dw` has an identical shape as `w` from the previous example. `dout` is also known from the previous example. `x` is similar to `dout` but it's `channels` is equal to `dw`'s `channels`.

I'm courios about what happens to the single values when performing such operations. I mean, this is in general just convolution between different tensors, but I'm currently confused about how to express this with for loops.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy - What is broadcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832923/numpy-what-is-broadcasting)

Comment: Also, this is a good reference: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: It’s actually not about the way how numpy handles arrays of different shapes but how this would be expressed in a „classic“ way. It’s like i don’t really get the which Operation is performed on which indexed element. I hope you get what I mean :)

Comment: "Single values" when multiplied with a N-D matrix, all values in the matrix get multiplied by the single value.  This is a subset of broadcasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `depth`, `r` and `c` are scalars, then

```
dout[depth, r, c]
```

is a scalar (if `dout` is 3d)

```
dout[depth, r, c] * w[depth,:,:,:]
```

`w[depth, :, :, :]` is a 3d array sliced from `w`, that is, the subarray selected by the `depth` index.   This is just the scalar times each element of that subarray, producing a new array.

```
dx[:,r:H,c:W] += dout[depth, r, c] * w[depth,:,:,:]
```

is effectively:

```
dx[:,r:H,c:W] = dx[:, r:H, c:W] + dout[depth, r, c] * w[depth,:,:,:]
```

`dx[:, r:H, c:W]` is a slice of `dx`, 3d like `dx` but a subset along the 2nd and 3rd axes.  If the slices are right, its shape should match the shape of `w[depth, :,:,:]`

I don't see any fancy broadcasting or special operations.  It's just taking matching size parts from each of the arrays, adding them and putting the values back in the right block in `dx`.

The color operators are just the basic numpy indexing operators.

---

```
dx.shape  (channels, height, width)
dout.shape  (num, m , k)
w.shape   (num, channels, height, width)
```

With the 3 dimensional indexing, `dout[depth, r, c]` the shape of `dout` doesn't matter.  This is just a single value.

```
In [295]: 10 * np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
Out[295]: 
array([[  0,  10,  20,  30],
       [ 40,  50,  60,  70],
       [ 80,  90, 100, 110]])
```

Multiplying by a scalar can be thought of as multiplying by a matching array  full of that value

```
In [297]: np.full((3,4),10)
Out[297]: 
array([[10, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10, 10]])
```

Broadcasting rules make it possible to do the same thing but with 1d or 2d or other size array.  But I don't see that happening in your examples, I won't get into that here.

Comment: Note that none of the *syntax* is specific to Numpy; you can verify this by defining a class with a very simple `__getitem__ = lambda k: print(k)`, then try it with an instance like `a[:,:,:,:]`; you'll see that `__getitem__` just got a tuple of `slice` objects. None of Python's built-in types make use of anything more complicated than a single `slice` object, but the capability is there for any class to take advantage of.

Comment: Thank you! I got it...I didn’t thought about slicing.