# In Neural Networks, can the shape of the hidden weighted input and bias be different?

Tags: neural-network

I am using [this link](https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forwardpropagation.html) to understand the basic working of a neural network. I understand that components of a neural network can be expressed as matrices.

In the explanation , the 'hidden weighted input' matrix is added to the 'bias' matrix, ***but*** [they have different shapes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt1WP.png)

I understand that [matrices of different shapes cannot be added](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1232842/629867). How, then does this operation take place? Or is it simply a typo?

Here's a description of both elements used in the link: [Hidden Weighted Input (Zh) and hidden bias (Bh)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKa0G.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy - What is broadcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832923/numpy-what-is-broadcasting)

Comment: @mcskinner Yes, it does. Thank you