# What is the difference between (13027,) and (13027,1) in numpy expand_dim()

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

These are two outputs in a chunk of code after I apply the call `.shape` to a variable `b` before and after applying the call `np.expand_dim(b, axis=1).`

I see that the `_dim` part may seem like a dead giveaway, but the outputs don't seem to be different, except for, perhaps turning a row vector into a column vector (?):

`b` is `[208. 193. 208. ...  46.  93. 200.]` a row vector, but `np.expand_dim(b, axis=1)` gives:

```
[[208.]
 [193.]
 [208.]
 ...
 [ 46.]
 [ 93.]
 [200.]]
```

Which could be interpreted as a column vector (?), as opposed to any increased number of dimensions.

Comment: Those outputs sure look different to me!  `shape` is just as important part of the a numpy array's identify as the numeric value of its elements.  What you call a 'column vector' does have different number of dimensions.  Count the [] nesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between `(13027,)` and `(13027,1)`

They are arrays of different dimensions and some operations apply to them differently. For example

```
>>> a = np.arange(5)
>>> b = np.arange(5, 10)
>>> a + b
array([ 5,  7,  9, 11, 13])
>>> np.expand_dims(a, axis=1) + b
array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]])
```

The last result is what we call broadcasting, for which you can read in the numpy [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-broadcasting), or even [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832923/numpy-what-is-broadcasting).

Basically `np.expand_dims` adds new axes at the specified dimensions and all the following achieve the same result

```
>>> a.shape
(5,)
>>> np.expand_dims(a, axis=(0, 2)).shape
(1, 5, 1)
>>> a[None,:,None].shape
(1, 5, 1)
>>> a[np.newaxis,:,np.newaxis].shape
(1, 5, 1)
```

---

Note that in numpy the transpose of a 1D array is still a 1D array. It isn't like in MATLAB where a row vector turns to a column vector.

```
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.T
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.T.shape
(5,)
```

So in order to turn it to a "column vector" you have to turn the array from shape (N,) to (N, 1) with broadcasting (or reshaping). But you're better off treating it as a 2D array of N rows with 1 element per row.

Comment: Your first chunk of code is like the equivalent of a Kronecker product but summing, as opposed to multiplying. I wonder if it has a name... Thank you, BTW!

Comment: @Mathtourist Numpy calls them outer operations, probably in the same spirit as the outer product, but I haven't encountered any of them in linear algebra.

Comment: Is there any way of going from `(1,16284)` form to `(1,16284,)`? The reverse operation?

Comment: @Mathtourist The reverse would be [`numpy.squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html). Don't you have a typo though and meant going from (1, N) to (N,)?

Answer (score 1):

(13027,) is treating the x axis as 0, while (13027,1) is treating the x axis as 1.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html

It's like "i" where i = 0 by default so if you don't explicitly define it, it will start at 0.